# show that the number $n = 11$ is not a sum of $4$'s and $5$'s

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't know how to get started with this question.
$11 = 4(x) + 5(y)$

What I've tried is :

> $x = 0, y = 2$
>
> $11 = 4(0) + 5(2)$
>
> $11 = 10$
>
> $11$ is not equal to $10$.

Wouldn't that be my base case? What more could I do to solve this question?

If i needed to apply induction to this question, how would I do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ can only be non-negative, then $x \leq 3$ and $y \le 2$ and you can just enumerate all possibilities. Otherwise, $x = -1$ and $y = 3$ is a solution

Answer (score 4):

If you allow $x,y$ to be integers, then the claim is false: $11 = 4 \cdot (-1) + 5 \cdot 3$. If $x,y$ need to be non-negative, there are only $6$ cases to check. So you just do that manually.